# Magento Nopin for entire site

Tags: magento, pinterest

I would like to add pinterest's nopin code to my site, inside the `<head>`.

I am using a custom theme and navigated to: `app/design/frontend/default/THEME NAME/template/page/html/head.phtml`

I also tried: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml`

I pasted the nopin code provided by Pinterest:

```
<meta name="pinterest" content="nopin" description="Sorry, we do not allow pinning of our copyrighted materials" />
```

No joy! Is there a location that I can post this or do I need to protect each image another way?

Comment: Have you validated that the tag is being rendered in your output HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover the entire site, the tag must be placed in

```
\app\design\frontend\default\theme_name\template\page\html\head.phtml
```

assuming Current Package Name is "default".

Flush the cache and reindex all the data

Tested on my dev site and is showing the message: "Sorry, we do not allow pinning of our copyrighted materials"

Also check your pinterest code. I use this one:

```
<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="beside" >
<img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_white_20.png" /></a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function(d){
     var f = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0], p = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
     p.type = 'text/javascript';
     p.async = true;
     p.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';
     f.parentNode.insertBefore(p, f);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Hope this helps